# Web browsers slow down SQL server Express

Tags: sql-server-express

Has anyone noticed the problem that SQL queries on SQL server 2019 Express take an abnormally long time if one of the web browsers is open on the Windows system? Specifically, I have a problem that a simple query takes 20 seconds or more. However, when I close the MS Edge browser, the query is done in less than a tenth of a second. E.g. I can also run a query, but nothing happens until I force Edge to close through Task Manager. The query then executes at the same moment Edge closes.

These symptoms are present on several different computers not just one.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a programming question. Maybe superusers is a better place for this? From what it sounds like, I'd more expect a memory issue rather than this being related to the software. If you are running SQL Express on the same machine as your browser, there easily could be a conflict with memory needing to be shared between Edge and the database engine, where RAM will have to be cleared to free it up for the database.

Comment: Might also be worth checking whether this is a *server* issue or a client tool issue. Do you see the same issue if you run the same query using the [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) tool?

Comment: I experience same issue on our .net application as well as inside MS SQL management tool. I doubt that there woul be any difference in salcmd but i'll try next time.